# Dynamic memory allocation for arrays and strings in struct in C

Tags: c, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to be create a struct, but I also want to write its array or string elements with dynamic memory allocation.

```
struct st {
    char *name[40];
    int age;
};
```

For "name" string should I use malloc before struct, or can I use it in struct also.

1)

```
char *name = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);

struct st {
    char *name;
    int age;
};
```

2)

```
struct st {
    char *name = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    int age;
};
```

Are both of them true or is there any mistake? And if both of them are true, which one is more useful for other parts of code?

Comment: There is mistake, you can't initialize struct members in the definition.

Comment: The first structure you show has an array of 40 pointers to `char`, i.e. an array of 40 strings. The second structure (alternative 1) will just have single pointer, who is totally unrelated to the `name` variable you define before the structure. The third structure (alternative 2) will not compile.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so can not we use dynamic allocation for struct?

Comment: Do you want to allocate the *structure* dynamically, or memory for the `name` member? Also, allocating memory for the `name` member dynamically with a compile-time constant fixed size make no sense, just use an array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I want to allocate the "name" member dynamically, static arrays forbidden for my homework, and I must use dynamic memory allocation for "name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an *instance* of the structure, an actual variable of it. Then you need to initialize the members of the structure instance in a function.

For example, in some function you could do

```
struct st instance;
instance.name = malloc(...);  // Or use strdup if you have a string ready
instance.age = ...;
```

Comment: Should instance be an pointer? can we write like "instance.name = malloc(..);" etc.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to have a pointer in the struct however allocate memory outside of the struct within the function you use it.

e.g.

```
struct st {
    char* n;
    int a;
};

void foo() {
    char* name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 40);
    int age = 0;

    struct st s = (struct st) {
        .n = name,
        .a = age,
    };

    /* TO DO */

    free(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a type does not create lvalues (like variable). It defines the format of the lvalue. In 1), you have correctly declared a struct type, but you seem to have assumed the similarity of the "name" variable in struct declaration will associate the pointer "name" to struct member "name". It does not work that way.

2) is syntactically/symantically wrong. You simply cannot assign a malloc() to non-lvalue (as you are declaring a type struct)

So, create a variable out of struct type as you have created in 1) and allocate memory in the struct variable member.

```
typedef struct st {
    char *name;
    int age;
} st_type;

st_type st_var;
st_var.name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 40); // This is how you will allocate the memory for the struct variable.
```

Remember, before you can do dynamic allocation, you need to have a lvalue just like you did for standalone "name" variable.

Comment: Can I use "name" in every function without allocate again after this process?